# Do jobs posters get feedback when we click X?

Tags: discussion, jobs

If I see a job posting and dismiss it because of a particular feature (e.g. relocation, salary range, frameworks), does the company get any feedback from that? I know if I was posting a job as a company that I would want to know if/why people aren't interested.

Comment: Jobs are specific to Stack Overflow, their meta site is MSO.